# Include artboard when saving as EPS in Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, artboard, eps

I'm pretty sure when I used to save an EPS file in Illustrator CS5.5 it would include the artboard but now when I save as an EPS file it crops the document to the edge of the graphics/objects instead of the whole page. I've been trying to find the answer all day on Google with no luck. I found a work-around by placing non-filled squares in opposite corners but I'm sure there is an option to simply include the artboard.

How do I include the artboard when saving an Illustrator file as an EPS in CS5.5?

Thank you in advance. This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Draw a rectangle the size of your artboard. Set it to have no fill and no stroke.

That empty rectangle will define the area of the illustration.

There's no real method to force third party software to see artboard dimensions. Some applications, such as Adobe InDesign, will allow you to define an import by art, media, trim, bleed, etc. But not all software does that.

Comment: That is what I have been doing but I'm pretty sure there is an option that lets you include the artboard when you save as an EPS.

If I save as a PDF the document maintains the artboard but when I save as an EPS the dimensions are defined by the objects not the artboard.

Comment: Well it depends upon what *other application* is reading the EPS. You haven't mentioned that.

Comment: Acrobat Distiller and Photoshop which are both Adobe products so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: FYI: The reason why I prefer to use Distiller is because even though I use the same PDF presets in Illustrator when saving a document as a PDF the file ends up being roughly 5 times the size than when I use Distiller.

Comment: I *really* don't understand your workflow.  Distiller is no different than saving as PDF.. only the Job Options may change.  The thing to realize is that and EPS inherently *has no background* so artboards don't actually exist in EPS files. If you save as a PDF, that will read the artboard as the "page".

Comment: In all fairness.. CS5 may be different, it's been quite some time since I've used applications that old.

Comment: Distilling may flatten transparency

Comment: @Metis Yeah I'm hanging onto CS5 for dear life. :)

Comment: I do still do the bulk of my work with CS6 :) Although I  also have a CC subscription. Just easier to ensure I can open the files 10 years from now without paying Adobe.

Comment: You can keep the art board as a white background when saving an .EPS if you don't select "transparency". To reduce file size when saving to .PDF in Illustrator do a "Print to .PDF"